# When is the derived functor of a representable functor representable?

Tags: derived-functors, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an abelian category and $\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \text{Set}$ a representable sheaf. Consider the $i$-th derived functor $R^i\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{F}$. My question is when is this functor representable. Since by assumption there exists some element $X$ such that $\mathcal{F}\cong \text{Hom}(X,-)$, we have $R^i\mathcal{F}\cong \text{Ext}^i(X,-)$. For every exact sequence in $\mathcal{C}$
$$0\rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$$
we get an exact sequence
$$\text{Ext}^{i-1}(X,C)\rightarrow \text{Ext}^{i}(X,A)\rightarrow \text{Ext}^{i}(X,B)\rightarrow \text{Ext}^{i}(X,C).$$
Since representable functors are left exact, that would mean that $\text{Ext}^{i-1}(X,-)=0.$ My questions is if this is sufficient for $R^i\mathcal{F}$ to be representable, and if not, what other restrictions on $F$ or equivalently $X$ can be impossed to make $R^i\mathcal{F}$ representable?

Comment: Prop 1.2 in "MODULES $M$ SUCH THAT $\text{Ext}^1_R(M,−)$ COMMUTES WITH DIRECT LIMIT" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.0557.pdf ) says that $\text{Ext}_R^1(M,-)$ commutes with inverse limits if and only if $M$ is projective. Hence we also need to assume that $X$ is a projective object.

Comment: Every module $N$ can be written as the limit of injective modules $I_i$. Hence if we assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of modules of some given ing $R$ and we assume that $\textbf{Ext}^{i}(X,-)$ commutes with limits, then we have $\textbf{Ext}^{i}(X, lim I_i)=lim \textbf{Ext}^{i}(X,I_i)=0$ and thus $X$ has to be projective.